Wireguard VPN behind Cloudflare tunnel
My question in short form: I would like to setup Wireguard on a VPN without exposing any IP address, but instead use a Cloudflare-managed proxied domain name. How do I do that?
In more details:

Situation:

I'm in country A, I have a VPS in country B;
I have a domain name vpn.foobar.com that, via Cloudflare tunnel, ultimately leads to my VPS;


Goal: route my traffic through my VPS so that from the point of view of some website, it comes out of country B;
To do this: I would like to setup Wireguard on my VPS so that I can connect to it without "knowing" the IP address (so in the configuration file, the peer is at vps.foobar.com instead of 12.34.56.78:12345).

How can I do that?
Side question: Is this even a good idea? Is there a more Cloudflare-ic way to do this?
